# Modifying 2 dimensional array of char in ruby

Tags: ruby

```
def initialize(ukuran)
    @kata = Array.new(ukuran, '@')
    @olah = @kata.join('')
    @cek = Array.new(ukuran, @olah)
end
```

I have those code in my simple ruby code that will make a `ukuran x ukuran` size of two dimensional array of char. When i want to change a character in specific index, e.g. `@cek[2][3]`, it will change its character in another index that comes with index 3 at behind, e.g. `@cek[0][3]`, `@cek[1][3]`

Is there anything i don't get in this type of array?? I'm new in ruby, as I know it will work fine in another language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simplify as follows:

```
def doit(n)
  Array.new(n) { '@'*n }
end

@cek = doit(3)
  #=> ["@@@", "@@@", "@@@"] 
@cek[1][1] = 'x'
@cek #=> ["@@@", "@x@", "@@@"]
```

Comment: thanks a lot...done well

Comment: This is the way to go, but you should briefly explain why the OP's approach did not work as expected.

Comment: @Stefan, yes, I should have, and will do, but it will have to wait until morning.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
def initialize(ukuran)
    @kata = Array.new(ukuran, '@')
   ## @olah = @kata.join('')
    @cek = Array.new(ukuran, @kata)
 end
```

Comment: no differences with that way..

Comment: It provide you ukuran×ukuran size of two dimensional array here I have pass @ kata in place of @olah

Comment: This won't work. After renaming the method to `init`, `a = init(3) #=> [["@", "@", "@"], ["@", "@", "@"], ["@", "@", "@"]]; a[1][1] = 'cat'; a #=> [["@", "cat", "@"], ["@", "cat", "@"], ["@", "cat", "@"]]`.